# Deleting Certain terms from appearing on the front end as links

Tags: php, functions, filters

I've put some thought into this but Can't really figure out what direction I take in getting rid of certain terms in my testimonial_category called 'home', 'homeone', hometwo. I only want to stop these displaying in a link format on the relevant page.

Here is the code the process's all the terms within testimonial_category, I was thinking I need to somehow add a filter that stops these 3 named terms appearing as links but could really do with some advice on how to do this.

```
<div id="main" class="floatleft">

    <div class="case-study"> 
        <h1 class="p-title">Testimonials</h1>
        <div class="breadcrumb"> 
            <ul class="filter group">
                <li class="all current"><a href="#">All<span></span></a></li>
                <?php
                $terms = get_terms("testimonial_category");
                $count = count($terms);
                if ($count > 0) {
                    foreach ($terms as $term) {
                        ?><li class="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><a href="#"><?php echo $term->name; ?><span></span></a></li><?php
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
```

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) has a convenient `$args` parameter which allows you to customize your query to meet your needs; in your case, it would be something as simple as:

```
$args = array(
    'exclude'       => array(1,2,3)
);

$terms = get_terms("testimonial_category", $args);
```

The array to exclude must contain the category ids of the categories you wish to leave out.

Comment: I'll try this solution, didn't even know you could exclude array id's like that.

Comment: You can check the link provided to see all the available options.

Comment: Thanks, I've learn't that now seems a very easy solution

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack... (hardcoding variables like this isn't best practice, IMO) but it's good example to get your wheels turning...

```
<?php
//...
foreach ($terms as $term):?>

    <?php /*If the term name is anything but not 'home' or 'homeone' then echo the list item */ ?>
    <?php if($term->name != 'home' || $term->name != 'homeone' ):?>

        <li class="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>">
            <a href="#"><?php echo $term->name; ?><span></span></a>
        </li>

    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Although I could see this working, I think the other solution is neater.